# error deploying asp.net mvc3 application with System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, asp.net-mvc-3

Maybe you can give a clue about this error, I have been googling and testing things for hours without result. I am using Mysql and Mysql connector 6.3.5. The error only happens on server, locally everything goes well.

The error:

> Method not found:
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet`1
>   MyModelEntities.get_my_aspnet_Users()'.
>
> StackTrace:
>
> [MissingMethodException: Method not
>   found:
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet`1
>   MyModelEntities.get_my_aspnet_Users()'.]
>   Utils.GetCurrentUserId() +0
>   Project.Controllers.ApplicationController..ctor()
>   +70    Project.Controllers.HomeController..ctor()
>   +29
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception
>   has been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation.]
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor,
>   Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis,
>   Boolean fillCache) +98
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +241
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type
>   type, Boolean nonPublic) +69
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType)
>   +67
>
> [InvalidOperationException: An error
>   occurred when trying to create a
>   controller of type
>   'Project.Controllers.HomeController'.
>   Make sure that the controller has a
>   parameterless public constructor.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType)
>   +182    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType)
>   +80    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName)
>   +74    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller,
>   IControllerFactory& factory) +196
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass6.b*_2()
>   +49    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<ProcessInApplicationTrust>b__a()
>   +13    System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action
>   f) +7
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action
>   action) +22
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Func`1
>   func) +124
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state) +98
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   httpContext, AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state) +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object
>   extraData) +16
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +8841400    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   +184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit more background info on your model would be needed to pinpoint the issue.

If I had to infer with only the stack trace...  It seems that in your HomeController constructor there is a call to get_my_aspnet_Users on your model class - MyModelEntities.  For some reason the code is not able to find that method.

Is it possible that you somehow have an older version of the model file that does not have the particular method your code is looking for?

Hope this helps.